# Is it worth writing tests for inputs rendering correctly alongside snapshot tests for Vue3 components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils, vitest

Here is an example test for a fairly simple component:

```
import { mount, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import { describe, expect, it } from 'vitest';
import ReplyItem from '@/components/fragments/ReplyItem.vue';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

const mocks = {
  global: {
    components: {
      'sc-avatar': '<div class="mock-sc-avatar"></div>',
    }
  }
};

describe('ReplyItem', () => {
  const reply = {
    user: {
      full_name: 'Test User',
    },
    body: 'Lorem Ipsum body',
    created_at: new Date(),
  };

  it('mounts correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(ReplyItem, {
      props: {
        reply,
      },
      global: mocks.global
    });

    expect(wrapper.html())
      .toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('Correctly renders the reply user\'s name', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(ReplyItem, {
      props: {
        reply,
      },
      global: mocks.global
    });

    expect(wrapper.text())
      .toContain(reply.user.full_name);
  });

  it('Correctly renders the reply body', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(ReplyItem, {
      props: {
        reply,
      },
      global: mocks.global
    });

    expect(wrapper.text())
      .toContain(reply.body);
  });

  it('Correctly renders the reply created_at', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(ReplyItem, {
      props: {
        reply,
      },
      global: mocks.global
    });

    expect(wrapper.text())
      .toContain(dayjs(reply.created_at)
        .format('MMM D, YYYY - HH:MMa')
      );
  });
});
```

The first test is already testing that everything rendered as expected (after props were passed in on mount). Are the next three tests still valuable, or would it make more sense to simplify to just a snapshot and then write unit tests for dynamic pieces and user interactions? Just looking to crowd-source some opinions on the matter. Thanks!